# How to fetch Many To one mapping data in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have two object in Java as

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private int color;
    @ManyToOne
    private Admin admin; 
    //setter-getter   
}


@Entity
Class Admin{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    //setter-getter
}
```

and on fetch

```
Admin admin=(Admin) session.getAdmin("user");
....
tx = session.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
list = session.createQuery("from Car where admin="+admin.getId()).list();
tx.commit();
....
```

but I am getting error. can anyone tell what would be the HQL query for this.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
list = session.createQuery("from Car c where c.admin = "+admin.getId()).list();
```